# Decode information from JSON Array within another JSON Array

Tags: java, arrays, json

Hello I am trying to get data from Json Array in another Json array. I am trying to parse it but, I am unable to do it. This is my JSON data.

```
{
"aggregate": "volume",
"dimension1": "queries",
"dimension2": "days",
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1998364102,
        "name": "Denso",
        "data": {},
        "values": [
            {
                "id": "2015-05-23T00:00:00.000+0000",
                "name": "2015-05-23 00:00:00.0",
                "value": 5,
                "data": {}
            },
            {
                "id": "2015-05-25T00:00:00.000+0000",
                "name": "2015-05-25 00:00:00.0",
                "value": 3,
                "data": {}
            },
            {
                "id": "2015-05-21T00:00:00.000+0000",
                "name": "2015-05-21 00:00:00.0",
                "value": 9,
                "data": {}
            },
            {
                "id": "2015-05-22T00:00:00.000+0000",
                "name": "2015-05-22 00:00:00.0",
                "value": 0,
                "data": {}
            },
            {
                "id": "2015-05-19T00:00:00.000+0000",
                "name": "2015-05-19 00:00:00.0",
                "value": 7,
                "data": {}
            },
            {
                "id": "2015-05-24T00:00:00.000+0000",
                "name": "2015-05-24 00:00:00.0",
                "value": 8,
                "data": {}
            },
            {
                "id": "2015-05-20T00:00:00.000+0000",
                "name": "2015-05-20 00:00:00.0",
                "value": 15,
                "data": {}
            },
            {
                "id": "2015-05-26T00:00:00.000+0000",
                "name": "2015-05-26 00:00:00.0",
                "value": 11,
                "data": {}
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

How to get data from "values" array? I need to get value and name from there. My JAVA code:

```
if (jsonObject.has("results")) {
    JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray valueArray = new JSONArray(jArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("values"));

        for (int j = 0; j < valueArray.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject name = valueArray.getJSONObject(j);
            System.out.println(j+"Value:"+name.getInt("value"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you prohibited from using a framework such as Jackson or GSON to parse the JSON for you?

Comment: use the iterator - `jArray.iterator()` and loop through to get the nested array.

Comment: Teena George- Could you please share the code?

Comment: It's an array within an array.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone. I got the answer. This code works

```
if (jsonObject.has("results")) {
                    JSONArray resultArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");                 
                    for (int i=0;i<resultArray.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject resultObj = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        if(resultObj.has("values")){
                            JSONArray valuesArray= resultObj.getJSONArray("values");
                            for(int j=0; j<valuesArray.length();j++){
                            JSONObject jObj = valuesArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            System.out.println(j+"  "+"Date: " + jObj.getString("id"));
                            System.out.println(j+"  "+"Volume: " + jObj.getInt("value"));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (jsonObject.has("results")) {
            JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            while(jArray.iterator().hasNext()){
                JSONObject valueArrayObject = ((JSONObject)jArray.iterator().next());
                if(valueArrayObject.containsKey("values")){
                    JSONArray valueObject = (JSONArray)valueArrayObject.get("values");
                    while(valueObject.iterator().hasNext()){
                        JSONObject valueObj = (JSONObject)valueObject.iterator().next();
                        System.out.println(valueObj.get("id"));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Iterate over the results array to get the value array. You have to add exception handling for any parser error.

Comment: It shows the method  iterator(), containsKey() are not defined for the type JSONArray.

Comment: I am using `JSONObject` from `Apache` `org.apache.commons.json` package. Probably you are using a different one.